# Excluding some returned results from MATCH query in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the MATCH query below(refering to users reviewing books):

```
MATCH (u:User {id:15})-[r:REVIEW]->(b:Book)
WITH u,b
MATCH (t:User)-[r:REVIEW]->(b)
RETURN distinct t
```

This cypher firstly matches the books reviewed by user with id=15. Then it uses another MATCH command to find any other user that has reviewed any book that has been reviewed by the user with id=15. However, the users returned include user with id=15 too. How can i exclude him?

Note that i used 'distinct' command in order that i don't get the same user 2 or more times. F.e. if user(id=15) has reviewed 2 books and another user has reviewed those 2 books too, i would get the last user 2 times without 'distinct'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to capture what you want in a single pattern, like so:

```
MATCH (u:User{id:15})-[:REVIEW]->(b:Book)<-[:REVIEW]-(t:User)
RETURN distinct t
```

When you have a single MATCH clause and pattern like this, because we differentiate the `u` and `t` variables, it will never match `t` to `u`.

If you want a shorthand version (provided that :Book nodes are the only things that :Users can :REVIEW, and that :Users are the only types of nodes that can :REVIEW :Books), then you can shorten this to:

```
MATCH (u:User{id:15})-[:REVIEW*2]-(t:User)
RETURN distinct t
```

Comment: Both answers work perfect! Thank you. I cannot upvote none of them because of new account.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a where clause to the second match that excludes users that are the same as the first user that was matched.

```
MATCH (u:User{id:15})-[r:REVIEW]->(b:Book)
with u,b
MATCH (t:User)-[r:REVIEW]->(b)
WHERE t <> u
RETURN distinct t
```

Comment: Both answers work perfect! Thank you. I cannot upvote none of them because of new account.